# least squares and orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, least-squares

I was given:
$S$, a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, where $\dim S = m \le n$;
A basis $\{v_1, ... ,v_m\}$ of S;
$x = x_s + x_s^p$, where $x_s$ is the orthogonal projection of x on $S$ and $x_s^p$  is orthogonal to $x_s$.

I was asked to show that the coeficients from the least squares solution equal the ones from the solution of the equation $V^T x = (V^T V)β$, which I managed to prove.

Now, in addition, I should prove that this equation still holds when I add one dimension to the basis of $S$.

Specifically, the prove must verify that the linear function associated whit the $m + 1$ case is bijective.

The problem: I have no cue on how to start...

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your problem? It's hard to read otherwise

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andrei. It's done.

Comment: @P When you say "add one dimension", do you mean that you're adding one zero-entry to the end of each vector?

Comment: @P Please note that, in most mathematical literature, the uppercase and lowercase versions of a letter are not assumed to refer to the same variable. So for instance, it is not immediately clear what you mean if you say "$S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, where $\dim S = M \leq N$" since $N$ does not mean the same thing as $n$.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I see your point. I meant to say that the basis for S now would have m + 1 dimensions.

Comment: I do not really understand the question.
_"this equation still holds when I add one dimension to the basis of $S$":_ please try to make precise what you mean here. You want to extend $S$ by adding one basis vector? _Any_ basis vector, or a specific one?
_"the linear function associated whit the $m+1$ case":_ which function?

Comment: Erik D:
"You want to extend S by adding one basis vector?"
Exactly.

"which function?"
The function associated with the invertibility problem (as the matrix VtV has to be invertible in order to express the solution as above)